# How to calculate the integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this exercise asking to calculate the integral of the function $y=(1-hx-2h^2 x^2) \exp(-2 x)$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ and to find for what value of "$h$" the integral is at its max.

Could you give me some help? Thank you.

Comment: May help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions

Comment: Use a partial fraction expansion. It leads to some [Exponential Integral Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#E1).

Answer (score 0):

for the definite integral I got $$-\frac{1}{4} e^2 h (2 h-1)+\frac{h (10 h+3)}{4 e^2}+\sinh (2)$$
you must differentiate this with respect to $h$